# Where could I get packages.conf file to build tiny SliTaz?

Tags: slitaz

As mentioned on [official resource](http://tiny.slitaz.org/), there is a need to obtain `/etc/packages.conf` first.

Now, I'm playing with live Slitaz 4.0 and there is no `packages.conf` in `/etc` folder (on the Debian the same).

Online information is very scarce, so, could you provide more details about this `packages.conf` file? My `uname -r` shows `2.6.37-slitaz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [official resource](http://tiny.slitaz.org/):

> The file /etc/packages.conf in the initramfs ...

*initramfs* file you can get in `/boot` directory.

It will be named as `initramfs...` or `initrd...`.

You can inspect this file with `lsinitramfs` or `lsinitrd` or even extact over `cpio` command. But you need to ensure if the `initramfs` is compressed or not via `file <initramfs_file>` command. If it will be *zipped/gziped* you need to use `zcat` instead of `cat`.

So create some directory (`<your_directory>`) and copy `initramfs` to it *initramfs* file. Enter to `<your_directory>` and (considering compression) execute:

`cat <initramfs_file> | cpio -idmv .`

or:

`zcat <initramfs_file> | cpio -idmv .`

Finally you can get `packages.conf` in `<your_directory>/etc/packages.conf`.

Comment: there is no boot folder in file system of slitaz and was not found neither initramfs nor initrd. But Debian system has a initrd.img-4.9 compressed file that includes /conf/initramfs.conf not packages.conf.